# Solution attempt direct sum in Axler 20 1.C

Tags: linear-algebra

I was doing exercises from Axler's Linear Algebra second edition, and then I encountered exercise 20, 1.C in the third edition.

So I wanted to ask if my attempt is right?

Suppose:

$U=\{(x,x,y,y)\in\mathbb{F^4} : x,y \in \mathbb{F} \}$

*Find a subspace* $W$ *of* $\mathbb{F^4}$ *such that* $\mathbb{F^4}=U\oplus W$.

So when $U_1$ and $U_2$ are supposed subspaces of $V$ these conditions must hold for $V=U_1\oplus U_2$:

(1)   $V=U_1+U_2$

(2)   $U_1\cap U_2=\{0\}$

My solution attempt is:

Consider $W=\{(0,y,z,w): y,z,w \in\mathbb{F} \}$  with $(x,y,z,w)\in\mathbb{F^4}$

For the condition $V=U_1+U_2$ (in this case $V$ is $\mathbb{F^4}$ and $U_2$ is $W$?) to hold then:

$(x,y,z,w)=(x,x,y,y)+(0,y-x,z-y,w-y)$

and $U\cap W=\{0\}$ :

$0=(u_1-v_1)+...+(u_m-v_m)$

then: $y=x=0$, $z=y=0$ and $w=y=0$

Hence $\mathbb{F^4}=U\oplus W$

Comment: In this case, $U \cap W \neq \{ 0 \}$. For instance, $(0, 0, 1, 1)$ is contained in the intersection.

Comment: Since $\;\dim U=2\;$ , it must be that $\;\dim W=2\;$ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

Try with $\;W=\left\{\;(x,0,y,0)\;|\;x,y\in\Bbb R\;\right\}\;$ .Observe that $\;\dim W=2\;$ .

Comment: Similar options: $W = \{ (0, x, y, 0) \mid x, y \in \mathbb{R} \}$ or $W = \{ (x, 0, 0, y) \mid x, y \in \mathbb{R} \}$.

Comment: That did it, I will try with those other options but the $dim W=2$ was the hint I was missing. Thank you